# vectorially finding neighbors to data frame rows

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have two data frames, below is a small sample of each:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1= c(3,4), a2 = c(8, 8), a3 = c(4, 18), a4 = c(9,9), a5 = c(17, 30))

df2 <- data.frame(a1 = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), a2 = c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7), 
                 a3 = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4), a4 = c(10,10,10, 10, 10, 10, 10,10,10), 
                 a5 = c(15,16,17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17))
```

I would like to examine, for each row of `df1`, whether it has "neighbors" in `df2`, where, by neighbors I mean observations that are different by at most 1 **in each column** (in absolute value). So for example, row 2 of `df2` is a neighbor of row 1 in `df1`.

The way I currently do this is the following:

```
sweep(as.matrix(df2), 2, as.matrix(df1[1,]), "-")
```

For row 1 of `df1`, and I have to repeat this for each row of df1. **Note that df2 and df1 do not have the same number of rows.**

However, what I would really like is to avoid doing this "by row", because my data frames have many rows. Is there a way to do it vectorially?

Comment: Ultimately, what would you like as the output?  E.g. do you just want the output to show the neighbor distances as in your `sweep()` example? Or, are you actually after the matching row pairs that meet your criteria?

Comment: @krads I would like to add a column containing the number of such neighbors

Comment: How do you want your output? Here is a vectorized work in progress ... `matrix(abs(rep(t(df1), nrow(df2)) - rep(t(df2), nrow(df1))), ncol = ncol(df1), byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: @Sotos this is a cool solution, however the dimension of your output is `N x M`, the number of rows of df1 times the number of rows of df2, which can be extremely memory-prohibitive for large data frames. Ideally the output would be like chinsoon12's answer below - although I'd rather use dplyr and not data.table...

Comment: @Omry just to clarify please: Where you mention in a comment, "I would like to add a column containing the number of such neighbors" do you mean **add a column to df2**?  E,g, for the correct output, do you want a column in d2 like `df2$df1_id` ?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Also, is your actual data only 5 columns or else how many columns wide is it?

Comment: It can be any number of columns and rows

Comment: Last question: Do you want the 'count' of the neighbors in df1 or the 'index' of the neighbors in df1?

Comment: It doesnt really matter. The most important issue for me is the vectorisation. I can later play with it and change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split your row of `df1` into a list, and then use `lapply` to achieve Vectorization:

```
my_list=lapply(as.list(data.frame(t(df1))),function(x) sweep(as.matrix(df2), 2, as.matrix(x), "-"))
```

each element of `my_list` is the computation result of each row in `df1`

```
my_list[[1]]
      a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
 [1,] -1 -1  0  1 -2
 [2,] -1 -1  0  1 -1
 [3,] -1 -1  0  1  0
 [4,]  0 -1  0  1 -2
 [5,]  0 -1  0  1 -1
 [6,]  0 -1  0  1  0
 [7,]  1 -1  0  1 -2
 [8,]  1 -1  0  1 -1
 [9,]  1 -1  0  1  0
```

Also, you can use `parallel::mclapply` which is faster than traditional `lapply`

Comment: Thanks Jim. However I thought `lapply` is just a neat, shorter form of a `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible `data.table` approach using non-equi joins

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(df2)

#convert into data.table and add row index for clarity
setDT(df1)[, rn1 := .I]
setDT(df2)[, rn2 := .I]

#create a lower (-1) and upper (+1) bound on each column
bandsNames <- paste0(rep(cols, each=2L), "_", rep(c("lower", "upper"), length(cols)))
df2Bands <- df2[, 
    {
        ans <- do.call(cbind, lapply(.SD, function(x) outer(x, c(-1L, 1L), `+`)))
        setnames(data.table(ans), bandsNames)
    }, by=.(rn2)]

#create the non-equi join conditions
lowerLimits <- paste0(cols, "_lower<=", cols)
upperLimits <- paste0(cols, "_upper>=", cols)

#perform the non-equi join on lower and upper limits and return the count
#`:=` add a new column in df1 by reference
df1[, Count := 
        df2Bands[df1, .N, by=.EACHI, on=c(lowerLimits, upperLimits)]$N
    ]
```

desired output:

```
   a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 rn1 Count
1:  3  8  4  9 17   1     6
2:  4  8 18  9 30   2     0
```

If you want to find the matching rows as well:

```
df2Bands[df1, .(rn1=i.rn1, rn2=x.rn2), by=.EACHI, on=c(lowerLimits, upperLimits)][, 
    -(1L:length(bandsNames))]
```

Matched rows:

```
   rn1 rn2
1:   1   2
2:   1   3
3:   1   5
4:   1   6
5:   1   8
6:   1   9
7:   2  NA
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to translate into `dplyr` :)

Comment: oh. do you only want a `dplyr` soln?

Comment: Would prefer it :) but if data.table is your favorite I will try to keep up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a good way to fully vectorise this problem, (apply family are really just for loops in a bow tie). But you can do it on a by column basis, rather than by row. If further improvement is required the size of the problem can be reduced after each column by removing rows that can be excluded from ever matching (this will cause an indexing headache, but is relatively do-able).

My attempt is below which uses a for loop (which could be replaced by lapply).
It returns a truth matrix, rows with a 1 can be matched to columns with a 1, which gives the pairing of neighbours.

```
col_comp = function(x,y)
{
    lx = length(x)
    ly = length(y)
    return(abs(rep(x,ly) - rep(y,each = lx) )<=1)
}

full_comp=function(df1,df2)
{
    rows1 = seq_len(nrow(df1))
    rows2 = seq_len(nrow(df2))
    M = matrix(1L, nrow=nrow(df1),ncol=nrow(df2))
    for(i in seq_len(ncol(df1)) )
    {
        matches = col_comp(df1[rows1,i],df2[rows2,i])

        M = M*matches
    }
    return(M)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Very interesting answer using just Base R. However `col_comp` is replicating x and y such that the memory load is `M x N`, the rows of df1 times df2, and can be prohibitive (imagine e.g. a million rows of each...)

Comment: This is true, the final return from the main function will have the same size though. If you want speed and memory efficiency I would recommend using Rcpp. Unless someone finds a good package/functin that does what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `library(sqldf)`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf( "select df2.*, df1.rowid as df1_idx
        from df2 left join df1
           on df2.a1 between df1.a1-1 and df1.a1+1
          and df2.a2 between df1.a2-1 and df1.a2+1
          and df2.a3 between df1.a3-1 and df1.a3+1
          and df2.a4 between df1.a4-1 and df1.a4+1
          and df2.a5 between df1.a5-1 and df1.a5+1")

  a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 df1_idx
1  2  7  4 10 15     NA
2  2  7  4 10 16      1
3  2  7  4 10 17      1
4  3  7  4 10 15     NA
5  3  7  4 10 16      1
6  3  7  4 10 17      1
7  4  7  4 10 15     NA
8  4  7  4 10 16      1
9  4  7  4 10 17      1
```

**Edit to show solution for any number of columns:**

```
library(sqldf)

cnames <- colnames(df1)

# main body of your sql
sql_main <- "select df2.*, df1.rowid as df1_idx
            from df2 left join df1
            on 1=1"

# join conditions (which will be added to above)
join_conditions <- 
  paste0( ' and df2.', cnames, ' BETWEEN df1.', cnames, '-1',
                                   ' AND df1.', cnames, '+1',
          collapse = '')

sql <- paste(sql_main, join_conditions)

sqldf(sql)
```